# Query to check the whether the class is already reserved on the specific time date

Tags: php, mysql, t-sql

Process to define a training/class schedule:

When user enters  ClassStartTime and ClassEndTime e.g. 07:20 to 08:00 (timings stored in the db in the same format)

How it will check in the database table if requested timing is not reserved/booked already.

In the db the entries of specific date 
e.g. 02/14/2013 could possibly be

ClassStartTime  06:00     ClassEndTime  06:40

ClassStartTime  07:00     ClassEndTime  08:00

it will check in the table

```
1   ClassId int(11)         
2   ProviderId  int(11)         
3   ClassName   varchar(25)
4   ClassDayName    varchar(3)
5   ClassAppointmentDate    date
6   ClassStartTime  varchar(10)
7   ClassEndTime    varchar(10)
8   ClassOccurence  varchar(6)
9   ClassEndOccurence   varchar(10)
10  ClassAfterDaysOccurence int(4)
11  ClassAfterDateOccurence date
12  ClassRecurrenceSetting  varchar(7)
13  ClassFee    double
14  classcapacity   int(4)
15  ClassAllowWaiting   int(1)
16  ClassPaymentMode    varchar(6)
17  Location    varchar(100)
```

Comment: When is a class considered reserved?  Do you have a StudentClass Table as well that holds students already signed up -- use that against the classcapacity?

Comment: so a student picks a time they'd like a class to be at, and the system tries to find a pre-scheduled class that falls within that range? e.g. "I want Basketweaving 101 at 10am"?

Comment: I am getting the reserved timings against a date explained in the question but I just need to check whether the time entered by user is between the timings of those record (get against specific date)

Comment: @Marc B : yes the same way, so it will check the availability of date and time requested by student

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MySQL, this'd work:

```
SELECT ...
...
WHERE '10:00' BETWEEN ClassStartTime AND ClassEndTime
```

given the "Basketweaving 101 at 10am".

Of course, if you ARE storing times in these fields, you'd be wise to convert them to MySQL `time` fields. Otherwise you'll end up doing string comparisons, which can/will fail.